# Simplify a list to a data frame & create new columns from numeric vectors in the list

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a fairly simple list:

```
ls <- list(560L, 4163L, 3761L, 287:290, 4467L, 3564L, 200:202)
```

where each row corresponds to a row in a data frame:

```
df <- enframe(c("tom", "dick", "harry", "sally", "sarah", "petra", "helen"), value = "name", name = NULL)
```

Because some row elements of the list contain a numeric vector it's not as easy as converting the list to a data frame and using `bind_cols` to combine the data.

So, I'd like to be able to simplify the list into a data frame and put each vector element into a column so I can combine with the df. The simplified list from this sample would be a data frame 7 rows by 4 columns. The non-reprex data will change and so the number of columns would represent the number of elements in the longest numeric vector and not just this sample.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you include what you've tried to make the question more clear?

Comment: @camille is tried a combination of lapply, do.call, and rbind, to no avail. My problem is splitting the vectors into their own columns.

Comment: Can you edit that code into the question? Even code that isn't working would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `unnest_wider`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
set_names(ls, df$name) %>% 
       tibble(col = .) %>%
       unnest_wider(c(col))
```

---

Or after `stack`ing into a 2 column data.frame, use `pivot_wider`

```
set_names(ls, df$name) %>% 
      stack %>%
      group_by(ind) %>% 
      mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
      ungroup %>%
      pivot_wider(names_from = ind, values_from = values)
```

If we needs the opposite

```
df %>% 
   mutate(val = ls) %>% 
   unnest(val) %>% 
   group_by(name) %>%
   mutate(rn = str_c('col', row_number())) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = val)
```

Or with `unnest_wider`

```
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    mutate(val = ls) %>%
    unnest_wider(c(val), names_repair = ~ c('name', str_c('col', 1:4)))
```

Comment: For the 2nd option, we can use `enframe()` if we do not want to convert names to factor.